# select only specified number of rows from first to last or in random for a give value of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

am trying to select random rows for a particular column value

df :

```
user    A
1   x
2   y
3   x
4   x
5   x
6   y
7   y
9   y
8   y
```

I want to extract only two rows in random where `df.B == 'x'`

ouptut :

```
user    A
1   x
3   x
```

code:

```
df.loc[1:2,[df['B'] == 'x]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want random 2 rows use [`DataFrame.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) after filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df['B'] == 'x'].sample(2)
```

If want first 2 rows use [`DataFrame.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html):

```
df[df['B'] == 'x'].head(2)
```